# Can a user/hacker change $scope variables in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, security

We are switching our app from classic PHP/HTML to PHP/AngularJS.

We are currently programming the login page where we have a form, it sends login/password to server via ajax, and if successful, gets e.g. private data of the user via JSON which is stored in the model and which changes the what is no the navigation menus via `ng-if` and `ng-switch`.

But we want to make sure this is secure enough.

Is there anyway that a user/hacker could change the value of `$scope.isLoggedIn` e.g. via Firebug or other tools?

```
mainApp.controller('loginController', function ($scope, loginService)
{
    $scope.isLoggedIn = false;
});
```

Comment: Yes, anyone with a debugger can change that value by setting a breakpoint. You can make it harder, but not impossible. As long as your backend is using authentication properly, this isn't a problem.

Comment: You should not rely on _anything_ coming from a browser to be _safe_. (It's not even a matter of changing stuff with Firebug - nothing is stopping me from directly sending requests to your API using cURL for example) All validation you did in classic PHP/HTML apps _has_ to be present in your PHP web API.

Comment: In most apps the views don't need to be secure, just the data.  So if they set "isLoggedIn" to true it shouldn't be a security concern - you should still have a session value on the server that lets you know if they are *actually* logged in - and return a 403 response if they aren't.  Then you can use something like https://github.com/witoldsz/angular-http-auth to bring up the login page anytime you get a 403 response.

Comment: Troy Hunt just put out a great article and course covering AngularJS Security Fundamentals: http://www.troyhunt.com/2015/02/introducing-angularjs-security.html